# Why would someone do this/that?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

Context: I'm walking with my friend, my friend sees something mean written on the wall for example, he says "**Why *would* someone do this?**.", how should I understand it? as:

1-" Why someone did this?."

2-" What motivated someone to do this?."

3-" Why would it occur to someone to do something like this?."

4-" What reasons someone had to do this?."

If none of the 4 sentences above is correct, please tell me what it means.

Comment: It's an expression of incredulity.

Comment: Okey, and  none of my sentences are close to it ?

Comment: You're better off asking your friend what they meant. The naive (in the sense of *unadorned*, not in the sense of *silly*) reading is that they are simply requesting a reason, but the wording is idiomatic of incredulity. Unless your friend thought you might know the answer, it looks like a rhetorical exclamation/statement.

Comment: It's all hypothetical  that's why I asked here to know the meaning in case..

Comment: The tone of voice should make it clearer whether they were asking a legitimate question or just expressing incredulity or dismay.

Comment: Although if they were really curious, a more idiomatic way to express it might be "I wonder why someone did that?"

Answer (score 1):

They are all plausible, but because of the context (the fact that it is an idiom and you were talking at the moment) I say it is the second one: 2-" What motivated someone to do this?. Which in turn really means " Why did someone do this?."

Answer (score 0):

They all seems like good explanations. Perhaps it should be written in the past tense 'why has someone done this', but the futures tense, as written, seems more common.